# mongoose Query was already executed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I was trying to learn a MERN stack beginner tutorials and i encountered this problem the query was already executed I'm getting this error whenever .findOne() is executed:
MongooseError: Query was already executed: elders.findOne({ _id: new ObjectId("636caae0e3c24f1df7b4e6b7...

```
router.put("/updateElders", async (req,res)=>{
const newAge = req.body.newAge
const id = req.body.id
try{
   await EldersModel.findById(id, (error, eldertoUpdate) =>{
        eldertoUpdate.age = Number (newAge);
        eldertoUpdate.save();
    })
}catch(err){console.log(err);}
```

Comment: Please add your code as text to your question, not as an image. FWIW, don't mix callbacks and promises.

Answer (score 0):

You should decide on whether to use callbacks or promises. You chose to use `await` (used for awaiting promises) and callbacks (your second parameter passed to `findById`. You should decide on which one to use, e.g.:

```
router.put("/updateElders", async (req,res)=>{
const newAge = req.body.newAge
const id = req.body.id
try{
  const eldertoUpdate = await EldersModel.findById(id);
  eldertoUpdate.age = Number(newAge);
  await eldertoUpdate.save();
}catch(err){
  console.log(err);
}
```

this code uses promises returned from `findById` and `save` calls and awaits those.